# Ruby daemon process does not execute at system boot time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, shell

I've written the following ruby daemon process code:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'daemons'

pwd  = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
file = pwd + '/../lib/background_service.rb'

Daemons.run_proc(
  'background_service', # name of daemon
#  :dir_mode => :normal
#  :dir => File.join(pwd, 'tmp/pids'), # directory where pid file will be stored
#  :backtrace => true,
#  :monitor => true,
  :log_output => true
) do
  exec "ruby #{file}"
end
```

It is supposed to be executed from a shellscript which executes on system boot.

```
#!/bin/bash
2 HOME=/opt/halogen/ui
3
4 ruby $HOME/daemon.rb start > log
```

When I execute this shellscript manually like `./test.sh` it works fine. The ruby daemon process executed. But, as per my requirement, it should be called at system boot time. When test.sh file is called by the system, it is not working and also the ruby daemon process is not executed.

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: How do you know that shell script is actually being executed at boot?

Comment: @JustinWood: because that script include other operations also and that are running properly when system boot

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your shell-script is run under the `root` user, which does not have `ruby` installed.

Try calling it using `su`:

```bsh
su halogen -c ruby $HOME/deamon.rb start > log
```

---

To further investigate your problem - you should see if there are any errors in your script.

Replace the first line in your script to:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash -ex
exec > >(tee /var/log/shellscript.log) 2>&1
```

This will make the `bash` script verbose, and write the verbose output to `/var/log/shellscript.log`. This should enable you to see whether there were any errors, and what they were.

Comment: under root user, ruby is already installed. i've checked by which command

Comment: and what does the `log` say?

Comment: log doesn't contain anything. its empty

Comment: See my edited answer - what do you see in the `sheelscript.log`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/0B03ypbi here is my daemon script, we are actually trying to run rb script at boot time which is linked in init.d. but still we are not able to run rb script at runtime.

Comment: Have you added logs to your bash script as I suggested?